# How to create thread blocks?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I have two questions.

**First:**

I need to create thread blocks gradually not more then some max value, for example 20.

For example, first 20 thread go, job is finished, only then 20 second thread go, and so on in a loop.

Total number of jobs could be much larger then total number of threads (in our example 20), but total number of threads should not be bigger then our max value (in our example 20).

**Second:**

Could threads be added continuously? For example, 20 threads go, one thread job is finished, we see that total number of threads is 19 but our max value is 20, so we can create one more thread, and one more thread go :)

So we don't waste a time waiting another threads job to be done and our total threads number is not bigger then our some max value (20 in our example)  - sounds cool.

**Conclusion:**

For total speed I consider the second variant would be much faster and better, and I would be very graceful if you help me with this, but also tell how to do the first variant.

**Here is me code** (it's not working properly and the result is strange - some_array elements become wrong after eleven step in a loop, something like this: Thread counter = 32748):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>


#define num_threads 5 /* total max number of threads */
#define lines 17 /* total jobs to be done */


/* args for thread start function */
typedef struct {
    int *words;
} args_struct;


/* thread start function */
void *thread_create(void *args) {
    args_struct *actual_args = args;
    printf("Thread counter = %d\n", *actual_args->words);
    free(actual_args);
}


/* main function */
int main(int argc, char argv[]) {
    float block;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int g;
    int result_code;
    int *ptr[num_threads];
    int some_array[lines] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17};
    pthread_t threads[num_threads];

    /* counting how many block we need */
    block = ceilf(lines / (double)num_threads);

    printf("blocks= %f\n", block);

    /* doing ech thread block continuously */
    for (g = 1; g <= block; g++) {
        //for (i; i < num_threads; ++i) { i < (num_threads * g),
        printf("g = %d\n", g);
        for (i; i < lines; ++i) {
            printf("i= %d\n", i);
            /* locate memory to args  */
            args_struct *args = malloc(sizeof *args);
            args->words = &some_array[i];

            if(pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_create, args)) {
                free(args);
                /* goto error_handler */
            }
        }
        /* wait for each thread to complete */
        for (j; j < lines; ++j) {
            printf("j= %d\n", j);
            result_code = pthread_join(threads[j], (void**)&(ptr[j]));
            assert(0 == result_code);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dump the thread micro-management and use 20 threads hanging off a producer-consumer queue: thread pool.

Comment: Could you send me some examples or links?